# Windows application in c# get slow in Button click due to Hasp dll

Tags: c#

In the Button click I had called other method which is in different class[**MODULE KEY** ] by creating Object for it..

The Process getting very slow It takes 1 to 2 Min Nearly to perform the button click event for the first Time..

**Sentinel Hasp Dll** is added in the **Class Module Key**.. and having a method(LOG_IN) in it.. Calling that method from my Main Form..

The process is very slow..But the function is working Fine.My Project Framework Version is 2.0..

Help me to sort out the Problem

Comment: If you call a third party dll and you think it's too slow... go and ask your provider of said dll for help. I don't see how random strangers on the internet can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion@nvoigt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I sort out the reason why It is very slow.. It is due to the **.net framework version.**

My Windows Project is in .Net Framework  version 2.0.. When i changed it to Version 4,Now there is no issues regarding speed.. It is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously (=> Sentinel Hasp dll) you want to perform license-checks upon the click of your button.

Let a random stranger from the internet give you his two cents (sorry - not even close to 34thousand-something reps -.-)

I had to implement a licens-handling/checking mechanism based on Sentinel-Hasp myself and was also concerned with poor loading times. 
I ended up seperating the whole thing off into its own thread. The initial loading of a license for a given ProductID was performed on application startup ONLY. After that, the presence of the license-key was checked by the thread in intervalls. if for some reason the connection to the key was lost, the checking-thread would trigger an event to the main-application.

the sentinel-sdk has some very good samples of how to implement custom
key-handling. i recommend checking those out!